# Unexpected behaviour with awk exit

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting, exit

I have next code:

```
process_mem() {
    used=`sed -n -e '/^Cpu(s):/p' $temp_data_file | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/\%us,//'`
    idle=`sed -n -e '/^Cpu(s):/p' $temp_data_file | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/\%id,//'`

    awk -v used=$used \
        -v custom_cpu_thres=$custom_cpu_thres \
        '{
            if(used>custom_cpu_thres){
                exit 1
            }else{
                exit 0
            }

        }'
    return=$?
    echo $return

    if [[ $return -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo $server_name"- High CPU Usage (Used:"$used".Idle:"$idle"). "
        out=1
    else 
        echo $server_name"- Normal CPU Usage (Used:"$used".Idle:"$idle"). "
    fi
}

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

    server_name=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
    custom_cpu_thres=`echo $line | awk '{print $3}'`
    if [ "$custom_cpu_thres" = "-" ]; then
        custom_cpu_thres=$def_cpu_thres
    fi

    expect -f "$EXPECT_SCRIPT" "$command" >/dev/null 2>&1
    result=$?

    if [[ $result -eq 0 ]]; then
        process_mem 
    else 
        echo $server_name"- Error in Expect Script. "
        out=1
    fi
    echo $server_name
done < $conf_file

exit $out
```

The problem is that read bash loop should be executed 4 times (one per line readed). However, if I write the awk code with an exit inside, read bash loop exits after first loop.

Why is this happening? In my opinion exit code in awk code shouldn't affect bash script..

Regards.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you create a small script that we can use to address this problem? In the current state, we are unable to verify your findings and help you with a solution or explain the culprit. ([mcve]).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the statement you make is false.

You stated:

> The problem is that read bash loop should be executed 4 times (one per line read). However, if I write the awk code with an exit inside, read bash loop exits after the first loop.

I do not believe that the script exits after the first loop, but is stuck in the first loop. The reason I make this statement is that your `awk` script is flawed. The way you wrote it is :

```
awk -v used=$used -v custom_cpu_thres=$custom_cpu_thres \
    '{ if(used>custom_cpu_thres){ exit 1 }
       else{ exit 0 } }'
```

The problem here is that Awk did not get an input file. If no input file is proved to awk, it is reading `stdin` (similar to processing a pipe or keyboard input). Since no information is sent to stdin (unless you pressed a couple of keys and accidentally hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>) the script will not move forward and Awk is awaiting input.

> *The standard input shall be used only if no file operands are specified, or if a file operand is '-'*, or if a progfile option-argument is '-'; see the INPUT FILES section. If the awk program contains no actions and no patterns, but is otherwise a valid awk program, standard input and any file operands shall not be read and awk shall exit with a return status of zero.
>
> <sub>**source : [Awk POSIX Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)**</sub>

The following bash-line demonstrates the above statement:

```
$ while true; do awk '{print "woot!"; exit }'; done
```

Only when you press some keys followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the word "woot!" is printed on the screen!

**How to solve your problem:**
The easiest way to solve your problem using Awk is by making use of the `BEGIN` block. This block is executed before it reads any input line (or `stdin`). If you tell Awk to exit in a begin block, it will terminate Awk without reading any input. Thus:

```
awk -v used=$used -v custom_cpu_thres=$custom_cpu_thres \
    'BEGIN{ if(used>custom_cpu_thres){ exit 1 }
            else{ exit 0 } }'
```

or shorter

```
awk -v used=$used -v custom_cpu_thres=$custom_cpu_thres \
    'BEGIN{ exit (used>custom_cpu_thres) }
```

However, Awk is a bit of an overkill here.  A simple bash test would suffice:

```
[[ "$used" -le "$custom_cpu_thres" ]]
result=$?
```

or

```
(( used <= custom_cpu_thres ))
result=$?
```

Comment: Very nice! And you were too nice not to mention that the whole script can probably be re-written in awk, with no calls to externals required. For instance `used=\`sed -n -e '/^Cpu(s):/p' $temp_data_file | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/\%us,//'\``, can be `awk '/^Cpu(s):/{used=$2;sub(/\%us,/"",used); print used}' $temp_data_file` , and of course all the other variables can be captured similarly, and tested in awk, without calls to external programs. O.P. please take note ;-) . Good luck to all!